# how to check date is between a range from models

Tags: django, datetime, django-models, django-views

I have a list of dates and I want to check if dates are in between the range then it will pass.

here range means I have model `Splitrule` which has `startDate` and `endDate`. I want to check if a date is between startDate and endDate.

what I have tried so far:

```
dates = list(set(OrderDetail.objects.all().values_list('orderDate', flat=True)))
        for date in dates:
            check_date = SplitRule.objects.filter(startDate__lt=date,endDate__gt=date)
            print(f'check date',check_date)
```

it prints:

```
check date <QuerySet [<SplitRule: testing>]>
```

Comment: The filter seems ok, it did find a SplitRule for one of the dates (can't know which by this code), but I'm not sure what you're looking for: should it print/return dates without SplitRules? should it print dates that have SplitRules? something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter your queryset like this.

```
OrderDetail.objects.filter(startDate_gte=your_date, endDate__lte=your_date).exists()
```

This will return True if the date is between startDate and endDate  of OrderDetail otherwise False.

Comment: Hey, `<QuerySet [<SplitRule: testing>]>` I have this queryset how do I get the data from this querySet ?

Comment: If you remove`.exists()` then this will return queryset @SandeepSharma